# Why does Scala consume 2-3x more RAM than competitors in the Computer Language Benchmarks Game?

Tags: performance, scala

Is it related to garbage collection? It just seems odd that it performs so well in all other areas and fails miserably on memory consumption.

Link: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/scala.html

Comment: Immaturity, perhaps? Also, a lot of constructs in Scala perform really poorly.

Comment: I would guess this one: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/scala.php .

Comment: The one with the hugest (3x) mem different is the `pidigits` benchmark. It looks like the Java version just prints each digit as it comes, storing very little. The Scala program builds an entire string first, and prints that, storing way more (http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/program.php?test=pidigits&lang=scala&id=2).

Comment: FTFY - Why do some of the Scala programs consume 2-3x more RAM than the corresponding Java programs in the Computer Language Benchmarks Game?

Comment: @ Owen - yes, notice that the Java pi-digits program written for multi-core has the same memory usage as the Scala program - http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/scala.php#faster-programs-measurements

Comment: Rafe, the scala compiler has been in development for many years, so I don't think it's immaturity. Can you tell us what scala constructs perform poorly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without addressing each case, in general, Scala is happy to create many objects, both small and large, to make your life easier.  If you *specifically* program to have a small memory footprint, then Scala can be only slightly less compact than Java.  Otherwise, if you're trying to make the program fast and easy to code (but you don't specifically pay attention to memory), it'll tend to be larger.

If anyone wanted to create small-memory-footprint versions of the programs and submit them, I'm sure they'd be accepted.

Comment: Maybe -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis would help for these small objects (wrapper objects for implicits): http://www.decodified.com/scala/2010/08/27/scala-rich-wrapping-performance.html

Or maybe that optimization is already included in -XX:+AggressiveOpts?

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral - Maybe looking at how the programs were run, and learning that the Scala programs were run on Java 7 with -server would help more.

Comment: @igouy I didn't see that. Unarguably, how the Java programs were run was obvious, and how the Scala programs were run was not. Instead of looking up how Scala programs were run here, I just assumed they were run precisely the same way they were run the last time I checked.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral - Unarguably, you didn't look, you just assumed. How the Java programs were run is no more obvious or less obvious than how the Scala programs were run - the build and run command-lines are shown for every program. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/program.php?test=spectralnorm&lang=scala&id=2#log